# Quickly Select and Fill Base Colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, fill

Here's an [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxDUet7wU_U&feature=youtu.be&t=7m12s) of the kind of selection/coloring I'm talking about

Is there a way in Photoshop to quickly select areas in line art, as in the video, and then apply base colors?

I've tried Magic Wand and Quick Select, but both run into issues with anti-aliasing on the lines and when fill is applied, white gaps are left between the fill and the line art.

Setting the tolerance of the Magic Wand too loose causes it to eat into the lineart or select the lineart in it's entirety which is wholly undesired.

Comment: As long as the lines are water tight, you can do this with the `Paint bucket tool`. Just make sure that tolerance is high enough, `Contiguous` is checked and `All layers` is checked. Now you can make a layer below of above the line art layer and `Paint bucket` all you want. If you place the layer above the line art, you should set blending mode to `Multiply`.

Comment: There's still the issue of the feathered edges on lines from anti-aliasing, even on the hardest setting brushes leave some gradient that becomes white gaps in the fill. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/9yFfPMq.png Should I just turn off anti-aliasing to keep this from happening? It'd certainly keep this from happening, but then the line art is aliased...

Comment: If I had to guess, either you have `Anti-aliasing` disabled in the `Paint bucket tool` options ( On the right side of `Tolerance` ) or the `Tolerance` isn't high enough ( You might want to first overshoot the tolerance so that it floods all over and then bring it down incrementally... just enough to stay inside the lines ).